# jEditorPane handling local images

Tags: java, image, jeditorpane

I'm working in a wysiwyg editor, with a jEditorPane, right now I'm trying to insert images via a JFileChooser into de editorpane, but it only inserts one image, I don't know how to do it, any ideas?

Here's how I'm inserting the image:

public void Imagen(){

```
int im = ImageChooser.showOpenDialog(ImageChooser);
    if (im == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){


            String Path = String.format("<img src=\"file:\\%s\"alt=\"Image\">", ImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            EditorPane.setText(Path );


      System.out.println(Path);

        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `setText` to start with, you're going to need to insert an image style element into the document

Comment: You might consider trying [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083776/inserting-images-into-a-jtextpane-error)

Comment: In the example they used a textPane and `setIcon` I tried using a textPane but when I get to the html source code it showed only something like `$ename="icon` not the path itself and I couldn't use `setIcon` with a jEditorPane

Comment: If the `JEditorPane` is maintained by HTML, then you need to insert an "img" tag into the existing code, via the `Document` interface...

Comment: Not sure if it's the right way, but as an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311188/inserting-images-in-jeditorpane-using-pane-getdocument-insert)

Comment: What I want to accomplish (if posible) is to insert images (not only 1) into the `jEditorPane` with a `jFileChooser` and be able to see the path in the HTML generated code with `"html/plain"`

Comment: I think I got it, thanks @MadProgrammer (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... somehow I managed to solve my problem, it seems `setText` wasn't good at all. What I did instead was get the path with `.getAbsolutePath` (I printed it just to be sure I was doing it the right way) and then insert it with the `HTMLEditorKit`, you got to be careful here 'cause I wasn't able to see the image at first because I was writing it incorrectly, any way here my solution:

```
public void Imagen(){

int im = ImageChooser.showOpenDialog(ImageChooser);
    if (im == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        System.out.println("Loading Image...");
        int caretPos = EditorPane.getCaretPosition();
        HTMLEditorKit e = new HTMLEditorKit();
     try {


    String Path = String.format( ImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
               System.out.println(Path);
         e.insertHTML(document, caretPos,"<img src=\"file:\\"+Path+"\" alt=\"some_text\">" , 0, 0, HTML.Tag.IMG);
       //  <img src="url" alt="some_text">

     } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }


        }else{
            System.out.println("Nothing loaded");}
}
```

Comment: Any way to achieve this using setText()? I'm having the same problem, but I'm using JTextPane as a mini-browser to display a web page, not as the editor, and I process my image tags using Regular Expressions. Maybe there is a way to set the correct path and then pass HTML to setText()?